# Accessing Azure Service Prinicpal details from a VSTS release

Tags: powershell, security, azure, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-devops-rest-api

Whilst we're able to use the Powershell Azure task in VSTS for a release, we also sometimes run F# scripts for releases, and as part of that, we want to deploy assets to Azure using a service principal. We already have the SP registered in VSTS, and Powershell can get to it - but is there a way for e.g. raw command line etc. to get to the Tenant Id etc. etc. so that we can manually use them? For example, as environment variables?

The only other alternative we have is to manually copy the tenant id etc. across to the release as build variables but this looks like a workaround to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can get the related information (e.g. Tenant Id) in a custom build/release step/task.

More information about build extension, you can refer to: [Add a build task](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/develop/add-build-task).

If you don’t know how to achieve it, you can refer to these steps to get all source code of Azure PowerShell step/task.

1. Set up a on premise build agent: [Deploy an agent on Windows](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/actions/agents/v2-windows)
2. Create a build/release definition
3. Add Azure PowerShell step/task and config it
4. Queue this build/release
5. Log on your build agent machine, check the Azure PowerShell step/task in `[agent folder]\tasks\AzurePowerShell`

The simple build/release step/task extension:

Files:

```
 AzureCustomTask

    Ps_modules (can be found in the Azure PowerShell step/task folder, refer to previous steps)

    Test.ps1

    Icon.png

    Task.json
```

Test.ps1 code:

```
$serviceNameInput = Get-VstsInput -Name ConnectedServiceNameSelector -Default 'ConnectedServiceName'
 Write-Host $serviceNameInput
 $serviceName = Get-VstsInput -Name $serviceNameInput -Default (Get-VstsInput -Name DeploymentEnvironmentName)

 Write-Host $serviceName
        if (!$serviceName) {
            # Let the task SDK throw an error message if the input isn't defined.
            Get-VstsInput -Name $serviceNameInput -Require
        }

        $endpoint = Get-VstsEndpoint -Name $serviceName -Require

        Write-Host $endpoint.Auth.Parameters.TenantId
```

Part code in task.json (input box to select subscription):

```
"inputs": [
    {
      "name": "ConnectedServiceName",
      "type": "connectedService:AzureRM",
      "label": "Azure RM Subscription",
      "defaultValue": "",
      "required": true,
      "helpMarkDown": "Select the Azure Resource Manager subscription for the deployment."
    },
....
```

Comment: Thanks. Does this mean that the only way to get to the connected details is via Powershell though? I'm wondering if we can get to it via .NET code?

Comment: @IsaacAbraham It uses vsts-task-lib to get the endpoint and it is powershell code, but you can call powershell script from .net code.